# Change MPVolumeView iPad Popover size

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, popover, mpvolumeview

I’m using an `MPVolumeView`. I have this code in `viewDidLoad` method

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] init];
volumeView.center =  self.view.center;
volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = NO;
[self.view addSubview:volumeView];
```

And even when there is no other element in the view, the popover is too small.

[image]

Is there a way to change/specify the popover size for the `MPVolumeView`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    MPVolumeView *mpVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y, 90, 70)];

    mpVolumeView .transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.4, 1.4); // increase its size 

   mpVolumeView .showsVolumeSlider = NO;
   [self.view addSubview:mpVolumeView ];
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only increase the icon size and isn't what I'm looking for. I need a way to change the popover height.

Answer (score 0):

You can override presentViewController method in your root view controller method and set preferredContentSize for presenting controller:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    viewControllerToPresent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 100);
    [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
}
```